# how to display current X-Y position of window in gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, window

For input into gnome-terminal --geometry. I would like to customize the gnome-terminal position upon opening it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `xdotool` to get the position of your current terminal window...

Install `xdotool` if you don't have it:

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

Select the window and display its geometry:

```
xdotool getwindowgeometry `xdotool selectwindow`
```

Answer (score 0):

got answer on reddit: `xwininfo`